# Pyrad client wifi connection failure

Tags: android, wifi, radius, pyrad

I've developed a custom server script utilizing Pyrad. The server operates smoothly, effectively responding to access request packets from clients. However, I encounter an issue where clients fail to connect to the network despite receiving an access accept packet. Upon confirming that the server dispatched the packet, and my Android phone (acting as the client) successfully received the response, I remain puzzled. A thorough examination via ADB indicates that the phone and access point have successfully associated, yet consistently present a "Connection Failed" status post-attempt.

I speculate two potential sources for this issue. First, it's plausible that the access accept packet might lack essential attributes necessary for the client to establish a seamless connection and facilitate data transmission. Second, given the utilization of the EAP PEAP protocol, it's conceivable that I haven't configured the security certificates and keys correctly.

I anticipated that upon dispatching the access accept packet, the groundwork for a successful Wi-Fi connection would be laid. However, the current outcome suggests otherwise.

I seek guidance on rectifying this issue, be it refining the construction of the access accept packet or configuring security certificates and keys for EAP PEAP protocol.